# Problem with callback error during Dash app implementation

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am trying to set up a simple Dash app that returns a value from a dataframe used as a "look-up table"; a screenshot of a sample test table is included here[image]

Within the app, a user can enter one of many states (this is the first column in above table), and the app should return the corresponding two column entries from same row in which the state exists in this dataframe. For example: if a user selected LA, the app should return "med" and "radio"

Unfortunately, I am getting a call-back error after a user selection.  My code is attached below. Can somebody please guide me on the way to resolve this? This is my first time using Dash - so appreciate any guidance!

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

df=pd.read_csv("test_lookup_table.csv", delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")
df.set_index('state')

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('On demand look up '),
    html.H3('Select from list of states below'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.state],
        value='LALA'
    ),
    html.Div(id='display-value')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown','options'),
    [Input('dropdown', 'value')])


def callback_a(i):
    return df.loc[i, 1:3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not mention the specific error, but I think I can see the problem. Your callback is outputing (`Output`) to the dropdown component's `options` prop. It sounds like you would want to output to something else, like a `div` or `p` component. You have a `display-value` ID for one `div`, so maybe that's where you want it to go? Try changing your callback like this:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('display-value', 'children'),
    [Input('dropdown', 'value')])
def callback_a(i):
    return df.loc[i, 1:3]
```

**EDIT:**

One problem is coming from setting the index to use the `state` column values. `set_index` returns a value, but you haven't assigned it, so nothing ends up happening. Use `df = df.set_index('state')` or include the `inplace=True` flag inside the method call.

That is causing the key error, because the `df` doesn't have the state values as indices, so you can't look for them. Now you can use `df.loc[i]` in your callback and it will be able to find the right row. You cannot use `[1:3]` here, though, because `loc` references by name, not value of the row/col, and you have no columns named with integers. You could do `df.loc[i].tolist()[1:3]`. However, with `state` as an index, you only have two values in each row (indices 0 and 1), so the `:3]` part is never going to get anything. You'll just get what's at index 1.

Lastly, and I should have mentioned this before, you've got the `df` set up as a global variable, which is generally not best practice. It would be better to use a callback to load the `df` in from your CSV file and add it to some component, like a `dash_table.DataTable`. Then you can have other callbacks pull values from that table instead of referencing a global variable.

Comment: Thank you @coralvanda. The above fix helped resolve the "keyerror" I was getting - but am now getting a  "dash.exceptions.nolayoutexception".   I tried to fix this by converting my return output to a dash_table.DataTable but was unsuccessful - and still have the same error.                                                                                      How can I get the desired rows from the return statement along with the column headers?

Comment: I reran the above code with the value in dcc.Dropdown = 'LA' (and not LALA as shown above) but it is generating two errors - a) options[3].label in Dropdown with ID "dropdown" is required but it was not provided and b)Callback error updating display-value.children.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Updated my original answer with more details. I hope this gets it working for you!